# Is it possible to measure maximal word wrap width in left-aligned text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is it possible to measure actual word wrap width in left-aligned text?

For example, saying below is aligned left. Depending on element width, it can be wrapped at word "their" or at word "the".

The width, marked red, does not coincide with element width, since wrapping occurs at random place when word does not fit the line.

[image]

Is it possible to measure this width?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not exactly what you want since it will modify your markup, but the trick I am using is to take your text and wrap each word in a span. I then look at each span tag and determine which one is the farthest right:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8q2274f/)

**Code:**

Markup:

```
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </div>

<div class="results">
</div>
```

JavaScript with jQuery:

```
var text  = $('div.test').text();
var words = text.split(' ');
var html  = '';

$.each(words, function(i, word) {
    html += '<span>' + word + '</span> ';
});

$('div.test').html(html);

var farthestRight = 0;
$('div.test span').each(function(i,e) {
    var left = $(e).position().left;
    var width = $(e).width();

    if (left + width > farthestRight) {
        farthestRight = left + width;
    }

    // Uncomment to see debug data
    // $('.results').append('<div>' + left + ', ' + width + ', ' + (left + width) + '</div>');
});

$('.results').append('<div>' + farthestRight + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the text width (and more) when you create a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) from the text node and read its dimensions with [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect).

```
function getTextRect( containerNode ) {
  // For simplicity, we assume plain text here
  // (no nested markup)
  var textRect,
      textNode = containerNode.childNodes[0],
      textRange = document.createRange();

  textRange.selectNode( textNode );
  textRect = textRange.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Clean up
  textRange.detach();

  return textRect;
}

// You can read the width with getTextRect( someNode ).width
```

You can see it in action in [this JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tinacu/1).

This method is well supported in IE9+ (doesn't work in IE8); Chrome, FF, Opera already [support it for ages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility). MDN doesn't have compatibility information for Safari, though. So I have briefly checked the demo in iOS8, iOS9, and with Safari 9 on the desktop – works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily create a `span` and fill it up with your text, one word after another, and check each time whether width has actually increased. As soon as it doesn't increase anymore, a line wrap must have happened, so just compare previous width to full width.

When finished, re-insert the original data.

```html
<div>This is a long text that wraps somewhere, but we don't know where exactly...
</div>
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

```js
var text = $('div').text();
$('div').empty().append($('<span>'));
var words = text.split(' ');
var lastWidth = 0;
for (var word in words) {
    if (words[word] == '') continue;
    var newWidth = $('div span').append(words[word] + ' ').width();
    if (!(newWidth > lastWidth)) {
        $('#result').text($('div span').text(text).width()).append('px');
        break;
    }
    lastWidth = newWidth;
}
$('div').text(text);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3fjoa0L/7/)

Comment: I made changed `$('#result').text($('div').text(text).width()-lastWidth).append('px');` to `$('#result').text($('div span').text(text).width()).append('px');` because you were checking the containing element's width and then subtracting the last measured span width from it, which was not giving the word wrap length.